# Are there USB Splitters in existence that I allow me to choose where the power goes based on program?

Tags: usb, power

Okay so, I have a device that has one usb port. This port only has enough power for one of my usb devices at a time. I would like to get a splitter to support two usb devices. However is it possible to choose where the power goes at any given time using programming? (Eg. send power to usb device A for 5 seconds and then switch to sending power to usb device B for 5 seconds, etc.). Perhaps my question is moot: if I got a normal splitter, would this work fine anyway?

Comment: What's wrong with a powered hub?

Comment: The whole device is mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that no, there are no such splitters. It would be too much trouble for manufacturers. You can, however, program such a splitter yourself using Arduino.